# does order of thread creation matters?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am writing a multi-thread program, where one thread executes a lot of system calls (like read, write), and other thread executes normal calls like printf.
Suppose thread A is for normal calls, and thread B is for system calls, my main function is like

```
int main()
{
  pthread_t thread_A;
  pthread_t thread_B;

  pthread_create(&thread_B,NULL,&system_call_func,NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread_A,NULL,&printf_func,NULL);

  pthread_join(thread_B,NULL);
  pthread_join(thread_A,NULL);

  printf("Last thread to be executed was %c\n",write_last);
  return 0;
}
```

By this, I found that the thread with system calls is executed last always. Even if I change the order of thread creation and joining, it is still thread B. 
I have two questions, does the order of thread creation/joining matters? and is it because of the system calls that thread B is always executing last?

Comment: Well, printf is making system calls under the hood (e.g., to write to the terminal, possibly calling malloc, which calls mmap), so I'd guess that is not the difference. How are you measuring which thread is executed last?

Comment: I am using a static variable "write last" .. Also, printf stores everything in the buffer first and then makes single syscall, right?

Comment: Yeah, usually on a newline (but if it's printing long lines there might be mallocs under the hood, and mallocs can trigger syscalls). Is write last protected (with pthread_mutex), when do the threads write it?

Comment: No its not. But since I am checking the last thread, so whoever will be executing last will have the thread to itself, right

Comment: Not necessarily, if both threads are accessing it simultaneously, either write could win. I'd try locking that static variable (just for sanity). What does it mean to update write last? Is that the last thing a thread does before exiting or what?

Comment: I added lock. It is still the same. Yes, that is the last thing a thread does before exiting

Comment: It may simply be that the thread executing system calls does more work, and hence takes longer. You could add a busy loop or a sleep to thread_A to test this hypothesis.

Comment: can you be more specific? Like add sleep in thread A before it exits? How will it ensure that?

Comment: It won't but you could make the sleep ridiculously long to make it highly probable (say 2x the length you've seen the program run for).

Comment: I added a sleep of 10 seconds. Still thread B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just measuring which thread finishes first, not which one runs first. Assuming they both run in parallel and start at roughly the same time, the one that spends less time working is going to finish first.

If you want to observe the sequence of operations in both, run the program under `strace -f`, but be aware that the overhead of tracing slows things down a lot and tends to eliminate parallelism in the traced program except when it's doing purely computational tasks with no system calls.

Comment: I can search for the syntax strace -f .. this is the first time I came across this. So this will tell me which thread started executing first?

Comment: Yep pretty much. But the answer of which one starts executing first might differ when run under tracing.. :-)

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks. I did run it. But since I am running on unix environment, it all went quickly. Is there a way I can store it some where, or a command where i can scroll up. I would really appreciate the help

Comment: `strace -o logfile -f ./myprogram` or similar

Comment: I saw it. Thanks a lot for the awesome command. Just one question, the thread that will be spending less time working executes first, then does it matter which thread runs first?

Comment: If you care which thread "runs first" (for example, if they'll both be contending for the same lock as soon as they start, and correct program behavior or performance depends on which one gets it), then you need to add additional synchronization to ensure this. Otherwise, your program should not care which thread starts running first.

Comment: I added a condition to check which thread executes first. Its always thread B (one with system call)..

Comment: By the way, I suspect the sequence of events on a dual-core machine is something like: 1. main thread running on core 1, core 2 idle; 2. main thread calls `pthread_create` for thread B; 3. main thread continues on core 1, core 2 starts thread B; 4. main thread calls `pthread_create` for thread A. 5. on core 1, either main thread continues or thread A starts running, while thread B continues on core 2...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful info :) appreciate it